# if-case pattern matching - Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Tags: swift, pattern-matching, if-case

I'm working through Big Nerd Ranch's Swift Programming book (2nd edition), and in the chapter on the Switch statement, there's a small section on in-cases and how to use them. When describing how to implement if-cases with multiple conditions, this is the code the book shows:

```
...
let age = 25

if case 18...35 = age, age >= 21 {
    print("In cool demographic and of drinking age")
}
```

When I try implementing this (exactly as it is) in my Xcode playground, however, I get an error ("variable binding in a condition requires an initializer")

It seems that the age >= 21 bit is the actual problem, as this

```
let age = 25

if case 18...35 = age{
    // Same thing
}
```

works fine. What am I doing wrong in the multiple-condition code?

Comment: Are you using Swift 2 by any chance? (If so, why?) Compiles fine for me in Swift 3.1

Comment: As @Hamish mentioned, it complies fine here too... what's the version of Swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 2.2 does indeed give that error message.  Swift 2 syntax would be `if case 18...35 = age where age >= 21 {`.

Comment: A quote from the section titled **Necessary Hardware and Software**: *This book is written for Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.0. Many of the examples will not work with older versions of Xcode.*

Comment: But really you should upgrade to Swift 3 – the latest version of Xcode doesn't even *support* Swift 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm working through Big Nerd Ranch's Swift Programming book (2nd
>   edition) ...

As mentioned at [the official book web page](https://www.bignerdranch.com/books/swift-programming/), the book includes Swift *Version 3.0* with *Xcode 8*.

Probably, you are working on Xcode 7.x or earlier, in Swift 2, it should be:

```
if case 18...35 = age where age >= 21 {
    print("In cool demographic and of drinking age")
}
```

Swift 3:

```
if case 18...35 = age, age >= 21 {
    print("In cool demographic and of drinking age")
}
```

*Remark:* if the first code snippet has been complied at Xcode 8 playground, it will complain about following compile-time error:

> error: expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition

with a suggestion to change `where` to `,`.

The same grammar applied when working -for example- with optional binding:

Swift 2:

```
if let unwrappedString = optionalString where unwrappedString == "My String" {
    print(unwrappedString)
}
```

Swift 3:

```
if let unwrappedString = optionalString, unwrappedString == "My String" {
    print(unwrappedString)
}
```

For more information about changing the `where` to `,` you might want to check [Restructuring Condition Clauses Proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0099-conditionclauses.md).

**So**, make sure to update the used IDE to the latest version (which compiles Swift 3).